# Как сделать всплывающее меню снизу вверх (как у приложения Пятерочка)?

Tags: java, android

Внизу экрана находится горизонтальная линия, когда проводишь снизу вверх, раскрывается меню. Искала в интернете, не нашла ничего, кроме PopupMenu.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте про android bottom sheet, по скринам похоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [BottomSheet](https://material.io/develop/android/components/sheets-bottom) вам в помощь.

  Вот [тут](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427) есть пример неплохой.
- В целом ничего вам не мешает сделать такую же штуку руками. Вы можете сделать отдельный макет с View в вашей XML разметке и сделать ей анимацию появления/скрытия. Это более сложно, но если вдруг по каким-то причинам вам не подойдет первый вариант. А с [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout) сделать это еще проще.

  [Тут](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/motion-layout/#0) хорошая код лаба по MotionLayout